# How to create DataTemplate with code? [MAUI]

Tags: c#, datatemplate, maui

How to create a DataTemplate with code?

DataTemplate does not have a VisualTree property like in WPF.

The [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate) doesn't help either.

There is an IDataTemplateController, but it does not control anything. <ignorable>weird MAUI times again</ignorable>.

Answer (score 4):

Found it in source code: There is a constructor parameter for a function which creates the view.

```
/// <Docs>
///   <param name="loadTemplate">A custom content generator to be called </param>
///   <summary>Creates and initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DataTemplate" /> class.</summary>
///   <remarks>To be added.</remarks>
/// </Docs>
public DataTemplate(Func<object> loadTemplate);
```

```
new DataTemplate(() => {
    var label = new Label();
    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("."));
    return label;
});
```

There is currently a bug in Binding and you have to specify ".", a fix is merged.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also create part of it with XAML and customize it with code-behind. I use this to set type-safe relative bindings, because they are not supported by Intellisense.

1. Create a ContentView as XAML and give a name to the element inside the view

```xml
    <ContentView
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
        x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyDataTemplate"
        x:DataType="vms:MyItemViewModel">

        <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="_template" x:FieldModifier="Public">
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </ContentView>
```

2. Customize the view inside MyDataTemplate.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MyDataTemplate: ContentView
{
    public MyDataTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TapGestureRecognizer tap = new();

        tap.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, new Binding(
            nameof(MyItemContainerViewModel.ShowItemCommand),
            source: new RelativeBindingSource(RelativeBindingSourceMode.FindAncestorBindingContext, typeof(MyItemContainerViewModel))
            ));

        tap.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding(Binding.SelfPath));

        _template.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
    }
}
```

3. Name the element that will receive your DataTemplate in e.g. MyItemContainerPage

```xml
<ContentPage
    ...
    x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyItemContainerPage"/>
    
    <CollectionView
        x:Name="_items"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

4. Set the element's ItemTemplate in MyItemContainerPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MyItemContainerPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyItemContainerPage :
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _items.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MyDataTemplate()._template);
    }
}
```

Note that it might be a good idea to create the template only once in a static field of the template class for instance, e.g. `public static DataTemplate Instance { get; } = new(() => new MyDataTemplate()._template);` and make _template private. And you might also use `.Content` instead of `._template`.